# do variables need to be instantiated before while loop python

Tags: python, json, loops, while-loop

i'm trying to scrape more 500 posts with the reddit api - without praw. however, since i'm only allowed 100 posts at a time, i'm saving the scraped objects in an array called `subreddit_content` and will be scraping until there are 500 posts in `subreddit_content`.

the code below gives me `NameError: name 'subreddit_content_more' is not defined`. if i instantiate `subreddit_data_more = None` before the while loop, i get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. i've tried the same thing with a for loop but get the same results.

EDIT: updated code, while loop now uses `subreddit_data` instead of `subreddit_data_more`, but now getting `TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable` despite converting `subreddit_data` to json.

```
    subreddit_data = requests.get(f'https://api.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}/hot?limit=100', headers={'User-Agent': 'windows:requests (by /u/xxx)'}) 
    subreddit_content = subreddit_data.json()['data']['children']
    lastline_json = subreddit_content[-1]['data']['name'] 

    while (len(subreddit_content) < 500):
        subreddit_data = requests.get(f'https://api.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}/hot?limit=100&after={lastline_json}', headers={'User-Agent': 'windows:requests (by /u/xxx)'})
        subreddit_content = subreddit_content.append(subreddit_data.json()['data']['children'])
        lastline_json = subreddit_data[-1]['data']['name']  
        time.sleep(2.5)
```

EDIT2: using `.extend` instead of `.append` and removing the variable assignment in the loop seemed to do the trick. this is the snippet of working code (also renamed my variables for readability, courtesy of Wups):

```
    data = requests.get(f'https://api.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}/hot?limit=100', headers={'User-Agent': 'windows:requests (by /u/xxx)'}) 
    content_list = data.json()['data']['children']
    lastline_name = content_list[-1]['data']['name'] 

  while (len(content_list) < 500):
        data = requests.get(f'https://api.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}/hot?limit=100&after={lastline_name}', headers={'User-Agent': 'windows:requests (by /u/xxx)'})
        content_list.extend(data.json()['data']['children'])
        lastline_name = content_list[-1]['data']['name']
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Yes, len needs to take the length of something that a) exists, and b) is a sequence or collection. The errors say that. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len Perhaps you could consider defining a generator to encapsulate the "get more" phase.

Comment: i've edited my code to show exactly what subreddit_content is (it is a list) and my print statements say that its current len is 100, which would be correct. i'm still not quite sure why this code doesn't work...

Comment: In the loop, you should use `subreddit_content`, not `subreddit_content_more`

Comment: I get the impression you get confused by the variable names, because you are using the wrong ones all the time. It's good to use meaningful variable names, but because this code is all about reddit anyway, prefixing every variable with "subreddit" is not necessary and makes it less readable. You could use `response` and `content_list`, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to just add one list to another list, but you're doing it wrong. One way to do that is:

```
the_next_hundred_records = subreddit_data.json()['data']['children']
subreddit_content.extend(the_next_hundred_records)
```

compare append and extend at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

What you did with append was add the full list of the next 100 as a single sub-list at position 101. Then, because list.append returns None, you set subreddit_content = None

Let's try some smaller numbers so you can see what's going on in the debugger. Here is your code, super simplified, except instead of doing requests to get a list from subreddit, I just made a small list. Same thing, really. And I used multiples of ten instead of 100.

```
def do_query(start):
    return list(range(start, start+10))

# content is initialized to a list by the first query
content = do_query(0)
while len(content) < 50:
    next_number = len(content)
    # there are a few valid ways to add to a list. Here's one.
    content.extend(do_query(next_number))
    
for x in content:
    print(x)
```

It would be better to use a generator, but maybe that's a later topic. Also, you might have problems if the subreddit actually has less than 500 records.

Comment: You could also do += instead of extend.

Comment: i think .extend() seemed to do the trick! i'm still wondering why i'm able to index a list the way i did (content_list is type list) but in case some one stumbles across this question with similar issues, i've edited my question to show the code for a working while loop. thanks again! :)